# Use enum to retrieve page bean 

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans

Consider the following two examples:

```
<c:if test="${errorMessage!=null}">

Welcome <c:out value="${homePageBean.currentUserName}"/>
```

When I look at examples of Spring controller to JSTL-enabled JSP communication, I notice that programmers hardcode the model object name in the controller and then hardcode the same name in the JSP. I'm trying to find a better way to do this.

I created an enum that contains the names of model objects.

```
public enum Bean {
ERROR_MESSAGE("errorMessage"),
LOGIN_PAGE_BEAN("loginPageBean"),
HOME_PAGE_BEAN("homePageBean");

private String beanId;

private Bean(String beanId) {
    this.beanId=beanId; 
}

public String getBeanId() {
    return beanId;
}
```

}

So in my controller, instead of hardcoding object name, I simply do this:

```
String errorMessage=failedAttempt?"login.invalidUserNameOrPassword":null;
model.put(Bean.ERROR_MESSAGE.getBeanId(), errorMessage);
```

But no matter how I try, I can't seem to be able to retrieve this "bean" within the jsp by using `Bean.ERROR_MESSAGE.getBeanId()`.

```
<c:out value="${errorMessage}" /> // works but uses hardcoded name

<c:out value="${Bean.ERROR_MESSAGE.getBeanId()}" />  // doesn't work

<c:out value="${<%=Bean.ERROR_MESSAGE.getBeanId()%>}" />  // doesn't compile
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: I don't see how `${Bean.ERROR_MESSAGE}` is any better than `${errorMessage}`. In both cases you have the same hard-coded reference in Java and JSP.

Comment: Well, the bean name could change. The answer is to use map notation with the enum's name as the key, but meh.

Comment: That the 'bean' name could change is one thing. The other one is to ensure that the right name is used to retrieve the 'bean'. This gets clearer when we assume different programmers control the components in play. But for me, I control both and it's only a question of pure principle. If there is no way to tie controller to jstl, then so be it. I'd rather ask, then live in the dark. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to reference the same "identifier" twice, be it a hard-coded `String`, a class name, or whatever else. Once in the controller and once in the view.

I see where you are trying to take a more programmed-approach, and it theory it's a good idea, but you end up having to injecting scriptlets in your JSP to make this happen. It's best practice to avoid this unless necessary.

I'd recommend some well defined constants for use in your controller classes (so you're not hard-coding `Strings` all over your Java code) and stick to referencing those `String`s by name in your JSPs (as you're currently doing). This is the common approach, used by the majority of MVC applications.

Comment: Beau, thanks for your contribution. I agree, that scriptlets are not a good way to code. As for constants, they're pretty much the same as enums with enums having a bit of an advantage on ensuring valid values are used. I understand your answer as "you're doing the best that can be done already"